# Closed range of $I-A$ for bounded operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a bounded operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ and $I$ is the identity operator.

**Question (1):** What conditions $A$ should have so that $(I-A)H$ is closed in $H$?

Clearly, if $A$ is onto this is true. Also, if $A$ is compact this is true. However, I am interested in the case where $A$ is a non-surjective isometry.

**Question (2):** What conditions a non-surjective **isometry** $A$ (with a fixed point) should have so that $(I-A)H$ is closed in $H$?

I don't expect this to be true for any isometry even if isometries have closed range.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that if $\Vert B(x)\Vert \geq  m\cdot \Vert x\Vert$ for all $x\in H$, then $\text{Im}(B)$ is closed?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Hi, I believe you thought of $B=I-A$? However, if $A$ has a fixed point $x\neq 0$ then $\|Bx\|=0$.

Comment: It could be bounded from below and without a fixed point. I didn't give you a very good condition, but it could yield one nonetheless.

Comment: @Keen-amateur It is necessary to take $m>0$, isn't it?

Comment: @freshman Yes that's what I meant, prior to the edit by OP.